# Configurate Injection of no inferface view beans in other MDB Bean by xml

Tags: java, xml, ejb

I have an MDB which needs other No Interface View Beans (Stateless Sessions beans)
unfortnately i have to do the injection via XML (ejb-jar.xml) Does anybody has a hint to achieve that in Java EE 8 (EJB 3.2). With Annotations all is working fine ..

```java
    @Interceptors(LoggingInterceptor.class)
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationLookup", propertyValue = "jms/P76MQ$4bd3dc121fdd4ae5a0730e990a4d14c0"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "messageSelector", propertyValue = "MandantenId = '4bd3dc121fdd4ae5a0730e990a4d14c0'"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "maxMessagesPerSessions<", propertyValue = "100"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "maxSessions", propertyValue = "1000") })
public class Protokollierung implements MessageListener {


    @EJB
    private PersonenIndexRepository personenIndexRepository;

    @EJB
    private BearbeitungsFehlerRepository bearbeitungsFehlerRepository;

    @EJB
    private PersonenIndexStandardisierung personenIndexStandardisierung;

    @EJB
    private ErmittlungFachdatenAenderungen ermittlungFachdatenAenderungen;
    @EJB
    private TransaktionsProtokollRepository transaktionsProtokollRepository;

    @Resource
    private String mandantenId;

    public Protokollierung() {

    }


    @PreDestroy
    public void runterfahren() {
        this.schema = null;
        this.mapper = null;
        MDC.clear();
    }

    @Override
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public void onMessage(Message message) {


    }

}
```

```
        <message-driven>
How to reference this ejbs ? 
i found something about ejb-local-ref .. how does it work ??
        </message-driven>
```

greets André

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
        <ejb-local-ref>
            <ejb-ref-name><classname>/<probertyname>
            </ejb-ref-name>
            <local><classname></local>
            <ejb-link><ejb-refname of linked ejb></ejb-link>
        </ejb-local-ref>
```

my error was that i didtn declared a local tag .. i thought .. hey i have a no interface bean  , why do i have to declare the type another time ..